# Add or remove char when string is small or big

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

```
string small = "12";
string big = "123456789";
```

**I need to get exactly 8 characters (addition and removal respectively)**
The result be like this:

```
small = "12      ";
big = "12345678";
```

Comment: What if the string is `123456789`, should the rsult be `12345678`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.PadRight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=net-6.0):

```
string result = small.PadRight(8);
```

If a longer string should also be cut, use:

```
string result = text.Length > 8 ? text.Remove(8) : text.PadRight(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain exactly `8` characters you can `PadRight` first (to have the text to be *at least* `8` chars long) and then take range (first `8` characters) to have *exact* `8` char long `result`:

```
var result = text.PadRight(8)[..8];
```